# Implementation restriction: You can only perform queries of the form Id='<some_value>' in Salesforce

Tags: soql

I am Using Salesforce SOQL query to get installed packages in an organisation. I tried the following SOQL Query

`https://ap15.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion+from+InstalledSubscriberPackage`

This query is taking too long nearly 16secs.To optimise the query I tried to do join between InstalledSubscriberPackage and SubscriberPackage

`https://ap15.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+SubscriberPackageId+from+InstalledSubscriberPackage+where+SubscriberPackageId+in+(+Select+id+from+SubscriberPackage+where+namespacePrefix+like+'test'+)`

I am getting an SOQL Exception

> Implementation restriction: You can only perform queries of the form Id='<some_value>' when trying to hit

Comment: per the [Tooling doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackage.htm), `SubscriberPackage.NameSpacePrefix` is not filterable which is why you can't do the LIKE operator

Comment: Your error message looks incomplete.

Comment: [
    {
        "message": "Implementation restriction: You can only perform queries of the form Id='<some_value>'.",
        "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
    }
]

Comment: @cropredy my initial query is taking too long nearly 16secs, anyway to optimise this?

Comment: yes - that query does take a long time. why can't you query using the Id (to find a specific package)?